# Modelling datamodel for document database

Tags: database-design, modeling, datamodel, ravendb

I'm starting out with Raven DB and am trying to wrap my head around the different document-model paradigm...

How would you structure the following, while being able to access a single event at a time, listing Albums, and inside that, listing Images.
Also I need to have a lightbox, storing single Images from different Albums.

```
+ Event
  + Album
    + Image
    + Image
  + Album
```

I tried to work out my root aggregates, but however I structure it, I wind up with having `Events`, `Albums` and `Images`, all as top-level Elements because I need to address them separately. This however seems like a straight copy from a relational scheme, which isn't really useful.

How would you structure this?

Answer (score 1):

I would store the images as attachments. That's assume there is no metadata that needs to be stored with images. Then, in each album I would simply store the urls to the images.

I'm not really sure what "event" means in this model. Does an album document have any meaning outside of event? If not, then I would just have an event document with the whole graph in it. 
I'm guessing that is not the case though, and that you want to access albums outside the context of events.

Next question, can an event be inferred from the document? If so, then I wouldn't model the event at all and just let it be defined as part of the index. Again, I'm guessing that's **not** the case.

If the two are really separate then there are two remaining choices that come to mind.

1. Just duplicate the album data whenever an event is persisted. Especially if album data rarely changes.
2. Store the albums as links, and use an include when retrieve them.

Comment: I've already solved it by now, but your answer's really what I did. I had to get my hearth around some DDD principles (only address aggregate roots), then I came to realize that I really only needed an Event, and all flows from there.

Comment: I recommend posting your final solution. I find this question comes up a lot, and the more examples on the web of solutions, the better.